# Group nested objects array by property

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I saw a low of question this type suggesting 'Unwind' & 'Group' stages, But it did not managed to get what i want yet.

After quite long aggregation pipeline i almost got what i need. If required ill post my entire initial documents structure and pipeline but I don`t sure if its necessary, It prettily big.
So i got up untill this step:

```
$group:
{
  {
  _id: 
    {
      Frequency:"$Frequency",
      LowLimit:"$LowLimit",
      HighLimit:"$HighLimit",
      Units:"$Units",
      Params:"$Params"
    },
    count:{$sum:1},
    Steps:
    {
      $push:
      {
        FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion",
        Result:"$Result",
        PassFail:"$PassFail",
        KeyIndex:"$KeyIndex",
        CatalogNumber:"$CatalogNumber",
        AppVer:"$AtsVersion",
        Id:"$Id"
      }
        
    }
  }
}
```

Which reproduce document like that:

```
_id:{
    Frequency:"XXX"
    LowLimit:"220.11"
    HighLimit:"285.89"
    Units:""
    Params:""
    count:16
}
Steps:
[
    {
        FPGAVersion:"XXX"
        Result:"232.00"
        PassFail:" "
        KeyIndex:"2305202109411720D27255"
        CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
        AppVer:"1.0.15.583"
        Id:60fd61a2d8034825203ac424
    },
    {
        FPGAVersion:"XXX"
        Result:"235.00"
        PassFail:" "
        KeyIndex:"2405202117040220A07687"
        CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
        AppVer:"1.0.17.607"
        Id:60fd61a2d8034825203ac42a
    },
    {
        FPGAVersion:"XXX"
        Result:"231.00"
        PassFail:" "
        KeyIndex:"0306202110431821A04704"
        CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
        AppVer:"1.0.18.618"
    },
    {
        FPGAVersion:"YYY"
        Result:"231.00"
        PassFail:" "
        KeyIndex:"0306202110431821A04704"
        CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
        AppVer:"1.0.18.618"
    },
    {
        FPGAVersion:"YYY"
        Result:"231.00"
        PassFail:" "
        KeyIndex:"0306202110431821A04704"
        CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
        AppVer:"1.0.18.618"
    },
]
```

What i need is the main grouping will still be the same, But i want the inner array to also have grouping by FPGAVersion. Like that:

```
_id:{
    Frequency:"XXX"
    LowLimit:"220.11"
    HighLimit:"285.89"
    Units:""
    Params:""
    count:16
}
Steps:
[
    {
        FPGAVersion:"XXX"
        Steps:
        [
            {
                Result:"232.00"
                PassFail:" "
                KeyIndex:"2305202109411720D27255"
                CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
                AppVer:"1.0.15.583"
                Id:60fd61a2d8034825203ac424
            },
            {
                Result:"235.00"
                PassFail:" "
                KeyIndex:"2405202117040220A07687"
                CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
                AppVer:"1.0.17.607"
                Id:60fd61a2d8034825203ac42a
            },
            {
                Result:"231.00"
                PassFail:" "
                KeyIndex:"0306202110431821A04704"
                CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
                AppVer:"1.0.18.618"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        FPGAVersion:"YYY"
        Steps:
        [
            {
                Result:"235.00"
                PassFail:" "
                KeyIndex:"2405202117040220A07687"
                CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
                AppVer:"1.0.17.607"
                Id:60fd61a2d8034825203ac42a
            },
            {
                Result:"231.00"
                PassFail:" "
                KeyIndex:"0306202110431821A04704"
                CatalogNumber:"333_GENERAL"
                AppVer:"1.0.18.618"
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

***EDIT***
A complete document example (some unnecessary data removed )

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"60fd4cdbbbbc873d1c831df4"
   },
   "Index":0,
   "KeyIndex":"25042021173703bb12345678",
   "SerialNumber":"XXX",
   "UnitName":"Unit A",
   "CatalogNumber":"XXX",
   "StartWorkDate":{
      "$date":"2021-04-25T17:37:03.000Z"
   },
   "FinishWorkDate":{
      "$date":"2021-04-25T17:44:14.000Z"
   },
   "WorkTime":"00:07:10",
   "TotalTests":4,
   "FailedTestsCount":0,
   "PassedTestsCount":4,
   "Status":"PASS",
   "AppVersion":"XXX",
   "FPGAVersion":"XXX",
   "Tests":[
      {
         "TestName":"Test A",
         "Status":"Passed",
         "TestTime":{
            "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
         },
         "Duration":"00:00:01",
         "TotalSteps":9,
         "Steps":[
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.00",
               "HighLimit":"0.45",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.40",
               "HighLimit":"1.00",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.01",
               "HighLimit":"0.20",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.01",
               "HighLimit":"1.00",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.10",
               "HighLimit":"0.40",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:00.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.50",
               "HighLimit":"1.70",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:01.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.30",
               "HighLimit":"2.00",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:01.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0.00",
               "HighLimit":"1.10",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:01.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"0",
               "HighLimit":"0.04",
               "Units":"A",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":" "
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message.."
            },
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message.."
            },
         ]
      },
      {
         "TestName":"Test B",
         "Status":"Passed",
         "TestTime":{
            "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:20.000Z"
         },
         "Duration":"00:00:00",
         "TotalSteps":1,
         "Steps":[
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:38:20.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":" ",
               "LowLimit":"AC",
               "HighLimit":"AC",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"FPGA Version"
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message..."
            },
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message..."
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "TestName":"Test C",
         "Status":"Passed",
         "TestTime":{
            "$date":"2021-04-25T14:39:27.000Z"
         },
         "Duration":"00:01:44",
         "TotalSteps":4,
         "Steps":[
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:39:27.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"69.00",
               "HighLimit":"89.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 6500"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:39:57.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"89.00",
               "HighLimit":"109.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 2B00"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:40:36.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"394.00",
               "HighLimit":"414.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value B500"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:41:11.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"699.00",
               "HighLimit":"719.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value B370"
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message"
            },
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "TestName":"Test D",
         "Status":"Passed",
         "TestTime":{
            "$date":"2021-04-25T14:41:55.000Z"
         },
         "Duration":"00:01:42",
         "TotalSteps":6,
         "Steps":[
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:41:55.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"107.00",
               "HighLimit":"127.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"0",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 5100"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:42:36.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"227.00",
               "HighLimit":"247.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 4800"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:42:47.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"282.00",
               "HighLimit":"302.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 2000"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:43:05.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"462.00",
               "HighLimit":"482.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 2D00"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:43:19.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"517.00",
               "HighLimit":"537.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 1570"
            },
            {
               "TestDate":{
                  "$date":"2021-04-25T14:43:37.000Z"
               },
               "Frequency":"XXX",
               "LowLimit":"697.00",
               "HighLimit":"717.00",
               "Units":" ",
               "Result":"XXX",
               "PassFail":" ",
               "Params":"Value 2500"
            }
         ],
         "Logs":[
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message..."
            },
            {
               "Type":"Info",
               "Message":"Log Message..."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The complete pipline so far (An example document output is shown before edit):

```
[{$match: {
  $and:[
     {StartWorkDate:{ $gte:ISODate("2019-02-04T11:15:15.000+00:00")}},
     {FinishWorkDate:{ $lte:ISODate("2022-04-05T14:15:15.000+00:00")}},
     {UnitName:{$eq:"XXX"}},
     {Component:{$eq:"TYYY"}},
     {FPGAVersion:{$in:["XXX",
                        "YYY",
                        "ZZZ"]}},
     {"Tests.TestName":{$eq:"Test A"} }
    ]
}}, {$unset: "Tests.Logs"}, {$project: {
  KeyIndex:"$KeyIndex",
  SerialNumber:"$SerialNumber",
  CatalogNumber:"$CatalogNumber",
  AtsVersion:"$AppVersion",
  FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion",
  Tests:
    {
      $filter:
      {
        input: '$Tests',
        as: 'test',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$test.TestName', 'Test A']}
      }

          }
}}, {$project: {
  KeyIndex:"$KeyIndex",
  SerialNumber:"$SerialNumber",
  CatalogNumber:"$CatalogNumber",
  AtsVersion:"$AtsVersion",
  Id:"$_id",
  FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion",
  Steps:{
    $reduce:{
      input:"$Tests.Steps",
      initialValue: [],
      in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
    }
  }
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$Steps"
}}, {$project: {
  FPGAVersion:1,
  Id:1,
  KeyIndex:1,
  SerialNumber:1,
  CatalogNumber:1,
  AtsVersion:1,
  Frequency:"$Steps.Frequency",
  LowLimit:"$Steps.LowLimit",
  HighLimit:"$Steps.HighLimit",
  TestDate:"$Steps.TestDate",
  Params:"$Steps.Params",
  Units:"$Steps.Units",
  Result:"$Steps.Result",
  PassFail:"$Steps.PassFail",
}}, {$group: {
  _id: 
    {
      FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion",
      Frequency:"$Frequency",
      LowLimit:"$LowLimit",
      HighLimit:"$HighLimit",
      Units:"$Units",
      Params:"$Params"
    },
    count:{$sum:1},
    Steps:
    {
        $push:
        {
              Result:"$Result",
              PassFail:"$PassFail",
              KeyIndex:"$KeyIndex",
              SerialNumber:"$SerialNumber",
              CatalogNumber:"$CatalogNumber",
              AppVer:"$AtsVersion",
              FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion",
              Id:"$Id"
        }

            }

   }}, {$project: {
  _id:0,
  FPGAVersion:"$_id.FPGAVersion",
  Frequency:"$_id.Frequency",  
  LowLimit:"$_id.LowLimit",
  HighLimit:"$_id.HighLimit",
  Units:"$_id.Units",
  Params:"$_id.Params",
  Steps:"$Steps",
 "Total":
   {
     $size:"$Steps"
   },
  Passed:
  {
    $size:
    {
      $filter:
      {
         input:"$Steps.PassFail",
         as:"res",
         cond:
         {
           $eq:["$$res"," "]
         }
      }
    }

      },
  Failed:
  {
    $size:
    {
      $filter:
      {
         input:"$Steps.PassFail",
         as:"res",
         cond:
         {
           $eq:["$$res","*"]
         }
      }
    }

      }
}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

- add `FPGAVersion` field in group by in `$group` stage
- second `$group` stage group by your required fields and construct the array of `FPGAVersion` and `Steps` fields

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            Frequency:"$Frequency",
            LowLimit:"$LowLimit",
            HighLimit:"$HighLimit",
            Units:"$Units",
            Params:"$Params",
            FPGAVersion:"$FPGAVersion"
        },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        Steps: {
            $push: {
                Result:"$Result",
                PassFail:"$PassFail",
                KeyIndex:"$KeyIndex",
                CatalogNumber:"$CatalogNumber",
                AppVer:"$AtsVersion",
                Id:"$Id"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            Frequency:"$_id.Frequency",
            LowLimit:"$_id.LowLimit",
            HighLimit:"$_id.HighLimit",
            Units:"$_id.Units",
            Params:"$_id.Params"
        },
        count: { $sum: "$count" },
        Steps: {
            $push: {
                FPGAVersion: "$_id.FPGAVersion",
                Steps: "$Steps"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't achieve what I want. It creates different document for each fpga version.

Comment: provide some example documents in your question.